# Mysql grant all privileges to user

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a problem, I created a database :

```
CREATE DATABASE laravel
                DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
                COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But when I try to grant privileges to user I receive a error syntax.

Could you help me with the correct syntax for mysql 8 ? Thanks

This is the problem:

```
 GRANT ALL ON laravel.*
           TO 'laraveluser'@'localhost'
           IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql 8 has no ide4ntified by any more with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html)

So you must use first CREATE USER and then GRANT

```
CREATE USER 'laraveluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON laravel.* TO 'laraveluser'@'localhost';
```